Improving weak model with little dataset
I have a dataset that has 20 features and 65 samples. I did data scaling. I also did feature selection in different ways. But this is the result. Test set evaluation:
MAE: 2.3462910007887787 MSE: 8.68486045116839 RMSE: 2.947008729401457 R2 Square 0.11298965960629503
Train set evaluation:
MAE: 1.9746175830150061 MSE: 6.369273380984405 RMSE: 2.5237419402514996 R2 Square 0.45535061890623796
adj r2 train 0.4008856807968617 adj r2 test -0.12354643116535957
I worked on different models and the best results were on linear models like linear regression. Do you have a way to improve the models and results?
